# replace factor value conditionally

Tags: r

I need to replace a value of one variable conditional on another variable as shown below. I'm getting tripped up on how R is handling factors.

```
# setup example
df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 0, 1, 1),
                  v2=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
df1$v1 <- factor(df1$v1, 
                 levels=c(0, 1),
                 labels=c("0", "1"))

df2 <- data.frame(v3=c(1, NA, NA, 0),
                  v4=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
df2$v3 <- factor(df2$v3, 
                 levels=c(0, 1),
                 labels=c("0", "1"))

# df2$v3
#[1] 1    <NA> <NA> 1   
#Levels: 0 1

# recode NA in df2$v3 to 0 if df1$v1==0
# df2$v3 should end up as 1, 0, NA, 1 and remain a factor

df2$v3 <- ifelse(df1$v1=="0" & is.na(df2$v3), "0", df2$v3)

# df2$v3
#[1] "2" "0" NA  "2"
```

Comment: Try, `ifelse(df1$v1=="0" & is.na(df2$v3), "0", as.character(df2$v3))`

Comment: thanks, @RonakShah, but I need the variable to remain a factor.

Comment: You can later convert it into factor maybe `as.factor(ifelse(df1$v1=="0" & is.na(df2$v3), "0", as.character(df2$v3)))`

Comment: My actual use case is a bit more complex, so I need to avoid that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# setup example
df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 0, 1, 0),
                  v2=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
df1$v1 <- factor(df1$v1, 
                 levels=c(0, 1),
                 labels=c("0", "1"))

df2 <- data.frame(v3=c(1, NA, NA, 0),
                  v4=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
df2$v3 <- factor(df2$v3, 
                 levels=c(0, 1),
                 labels=c("0", "1"))
df2$v3[which(df1$v1==0)] <- 0

sapply(df2,class)
#       v3        v4 
# "factor" "numeric"
```

Comment: thanks, @nathanesau. this does not seem to account for the conditional `is.na()`. it happens to work out fine for the original toy example, so i modified `df1$v1` to be (1, 0, 1, 1) to show this.

Comment: I corrected another mistake in the example. Your basic idea works if extended to `df2$v3[which(df1$v1==0 & is.na(df2$v3))] <- 0`